# Showing font from string ascii value in java

Tags: java

I need to show a font from an ascii value. The following code is working fine:

```
String font = Character.toString((char) 0x0627);
```

In my case, `0x0627` value is stored in a string variable like `String strValue = "0x0627";`

Now how can i use this `strValue` in my above code?

Comment: Sorry, you want to show a font from a hex value?  I don't even know what that means...

Comment: Terminology: That's not an ASCII value; It's a UTF-16 code unit. And that particular UTF-16 code unit '\u0627' is the single code unit for the Unicode codepoint U+0627 "ا". Some codepoints need two UTF-16 code units. For example, U+1F6B2 "" is "\uD83D\uDEB2". So, would your strValue be one of  {"0xD83D", "0xDEB2"} or "0x1F6B2"? Or, would  just not be in your problem domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
String strValue = "0x0627";
String font = Character.toString((char) Integer.decode(strValue).intValue());
//-------------------------------------^-Convert String to Hex-^
```

It is the equivalent of :

```
String font = Character.toString((char) 0x0627);
```